# Android - null object reference when iterating List

Tags: java, android, nullreferenceexception

I'm trying to copy a List 'usrs' which is created in an Inner class to a different list 'team_memebers'.
After copying I try to iterate 'team_memebers' in the FOR loop, but I get a 'null object reference' error.
The 'users' list contains the returned objects, tested via debug prints.

```
public class ListNodeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    private ParseObject parse_task=null;
    private List<String> team_memebers=null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_node);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> usrs, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

                team_memebers = new ArrayList<String>(usrs.size());
                for (ParseObject prso:usrs) {
                    team_memebers.add(new String(prso.getString("Username")));
                }
            } else {//handle the error
            }
        }
    });

    for (String str:team_memebers)
    {
        empolyeeSpinnerAdapter.add(str);
    }
}
```

**Stack trace**

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2, PID: 14490
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2/il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2.ListNodeActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
  Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.util.Iterator java.util.List.iterator()' on a null object reference
     at il.ac.shenkar.david.todolistex2.ListNodeActivity.onCreate(ListNodeActivity.java:116)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6251)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1107)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2369)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Have you tried a normal for loop with counter instead of a foreach for loop?
Something like ``for (int i = 0; i< team_memebers.size(); i++)
{
 employeeSpinnerAdapter.add(team_memebers.get(i);
}``

Comment: is query.findInBackground in another thread...

Comment: @chalarangelo, Yes, it fails on .size(), as it appears team_members is null.

Comment: @Xoce, no, but I tried query.find() and got the same issue.

Comment: post more code, where is team_memebers declared??

Comment: @Xoce, Added more code.

Comment: Post your stacktrace pls.

Comment: @NathanielD.Waggoner, Added stack trace.

Comment: You're statement is that the NPE is on the for(ParseObject prso: users)?  The way this code is written it should probably NPE on the for(String str: teammembers) as I don't see you waiting for the query.findInBackground() call to finish before doing that interation.  Can you highlight what line the NPE actually occurs on?  I can't tell which it is based on the stack as you have two for(iter) loops.

Comment: I get the error in the '(String str : team_memebers)' loop. I tried placing it in the 'query.findInBackground()' call block, but I get a message - "variable input is accessed within inner class; needs to be declared final"

Comment: @NathanielD.Waggoner, to correct my previous comment, I get the error message regarding the '...needs to be declared final' on 'empolyeeSpinnerAdapter'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is that you aren't iterating after copying list.
`query.findInBackground()` is an async callback and therefore, isn't executed immediately. Because your iteration loop is *PLACED* below that callback, doesn't mean it will be executed after callback executes. Just put your loop inside callback like this:

```
query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        public void done(List<ParseObject> usrs, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {

            team_memebers = new ArrayList<String>(usrs.size());
            for (ParseObject prso:usrs) {
                team_memebers.add(new String(prso.getString("Username")));
            }
            for (String str:team_memebers)
            {
                empolyeeSpinnerAdapter.add(str);
            }
        } else {//handle the error
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried placing it in the 'query.findInBackground()' call block, but I get a message - "variable input is accessed within inner class; needs to be declared final"

Comment: On which variable do you get this message? `str` or `team_memebers`?

Comment: Anyways, I suggest you to not assign `null` to `team_memebers`, instead declare it final and initialise with empty list:
`private final List<String> team_memebers = new ArrayList<>();`
and remove this line:
`team_memebers = new ArrayList<String>(usrs.size());`
also declare `str` as final in your loop:
`for (final String str:team_memebers)`

Comment: On 'empolyeeSpinnerAdapter'

Comment: Then declare `str` as final as I said.

Comment: Resolved it by moving the creation of 'empolyeeSpinnerAdapter' out of the 'create' method.